# How to measure the pairwise cosine for a data matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, cosine-similarity

Assume there is a data matrix (`MATLAB`)

```
X = [0.8147, 0.9134, 0.2785, 0.9649, 0.9572;
     0.9058, 0.6324, 0.5469, 0.1576, 0.4854;
     0.1270, 0.0975, 0.9575, 0.9706, 0.8003]
```

Each column represent a feature vector for a sample.
What is the fastest way to get the pairwise consine similarity measure in `X` in `MATLAB`? such as we want to compute the symmetric `S` is `5X5` matrix, the element in `S(3,4)` is the consine between the third column and fourth column.

*Note*: The consine measurment `cos(a,b)` means the angle bettween vector `a` and `b`.

Comment: Please tell us how you define the cosine similarity, and give an example result. If you have the Statistics toolbox, `1-squareform(pdist(X.','cosine'))` probably does what you want

Comment: I added the note. Thanks.

Comment: That's hardly clarifying :-/ What's the output for your proposed input? Did you check my code?

Comment: I am checking and will see. thanks

Comment: The `1-squareform(pdist(X.','cosine'))` works.

Comment: Great. I added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, use [`pdist`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) with the `'cosine'` option, followed by [`squareform`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html). Note that:

- `pdist` considers *rows*, not columns, as observations. So you need to transpose the input.
- The output is 1 minus the cosine similarity. So you need to subtract the result from 1.
- To get the result in the form of a symmetric matrix apply `squareform`.

So, you can use

```
S = 1 - squareform(pdist(X.', 'cosine'));
```